# Is there a way to create a bar bones flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I commonly create quick small flutter projects to test out a behaviour or reproduce a bug in a minimal example.

Whenever I use the flutter create command, flutter creates a counter app example. I then have to proceed to delete a bunch of unneeded counter stuff from the app, along with a large amount of comments.

Is there an option to create a minimal flutter project that contains no comments and just an empty scaffold?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `--sample` option in `flutter create` command.

```
flutter create  --sample=material.Scaffold.1 my_app_name
```

this command will create a project with lib/main.dart file like this without comments:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text('You have pressed the button $_count times.')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => _count++),
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```